# Openchange Build Issues (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, samba

I am in the process of trying to test out OpenChange and wanted to know if anyone has successfully implemented this software in a a live production environment and what their thoughts are.

Additionally, i am having a specific issue when trying to build the software which i am looking for assistance with. I am running through the instructions and can not get past building the software package. I have been stuck at this error for a few days and am looking for any assistance anyone can give me:

```
Compiling mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.c with -fPIC
mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.c: In function ‘mapiproxy_op_bind’:
mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.c:258:27: error: ‘DCESRV_CALL_STATE_FLAG_MULTIPLEXED’ undeclared (first use in this function)
dce_call->state_flags |= DCESRV_CALL_STATE_FLAG_MULTIPLEXED;
^
mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.c:258:27: note: each undeclared identifier is     reported only once for each function it appears in
mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.c: At top level:
mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.c:735:13: warning: ‘dcesrv_mapiproxy_lp_defaults’     defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
static bool dcesrv_mapiproxy_lp_defaults(struct loadparm_context lp_ctx)
^
make: ** [mapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy.po] Error 1
```

I have searched around for a few days as i mentioned and have hit a wall. I am still relatively new to using this forum so please be kind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...looks like my the version of Samba i downloaded from the repository wasn't the newest version and that was causing my problems. I posted this same question as an issue on GitHub for the Openchange project and got some feedback that Samba 4.1.18 or greater is needed to avoid this error...